# Hi! I am trying to center this code but it is not centering. I can not figure out what I did wrong

Tags: html, css

The text "transition: margin-left 5s;" should be in the center. But it is not and I can not figure out what wrong I did in the code.
Please note: text-align: left is not also working

Here is HTML code

```
<aside class="property-detail">
    <small>
       When we use shorthand version of transition, we use like this: 
       Property name | Duration
       <pre>
          <code>
             <span class="code">transition: margin-left 5s;</span>
          </code>
       </pre>
   </small>
 </aside>
```

Here is CSS code

```
.property-detail {
    background-color: #14213d;
    border-radius: 20px;
    padding: 20px;
    margin: 20px;

}
pre {
    background-color: #000000;
    width: 60%;
    height: 50%;
    border-radius: 20px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 10px;
    text-align: left;
}

code {
    text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: "text-align: right" works btw

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem comes with `<pre>` element.
It seems it has the intrinsic style `white-space: pre;`.
So my suggestion is to kill the intrinsic `white-space` and center `<code>` element.(I have used grid approach)

```css
/* Added this for text visibility */
body {
  color: white;
}
.property-detail {
  background-color: #14213d;
  border-radius: 20px;
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 20px;
}
pre {
  background-color: #000000;
  width: 60%;
  height: 50%;
  border-radius: 20px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 10px;
  /* text-align: left; */

  /* Added */
  /* To remove white-space: pre given by pre element */
  white-space: normal;
  /* To move the code center */
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
}

/* code {
  text-align: center;
} */
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <title>Static Template</title>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <aside class="property-detail">
      <small>
        When we use shorthand version of transition, we use like this: Property
        name | Duration
        <pre>
            <code>
               <span class="code">transition: margin-left 5s;</span>
            </code>
         </pre>
      </small>
    </aside>
  </body>
</html>
```

[image: Outcome]

I hope this will help you.